# Some Dates not recognized with Lookup when Calculated, but will when manually typed

Tags: excel, date, datetime, formula

I am stumped and spent so long trying to figure this out.  I don't know why it is doing this, nor how to fix it.  I hope someone can guide/help with this.

I have a worksheet. In that worksheet, there is a Date column and a formula. The formula is to match to that same Date (or lookup the date) but 2 hours before the date.  Then it returns a number in column B.

The problem is it will recognize some dates and not others when I calculate the date.   That same date that it did not recognize, if I manually type the date (and then use that cell as a reference for the lookup, it will work.

Another thing I found in my testing is instead of adding 2 hours, I add 2 hours and 1 minute, then maybe that specific date will work. But that solution does not work for all the dates that do not work. Each one requires a different time adjustments (in minutes. maybe one needs 1, one needs 3, etc.) to make work. So that was not the solution.

My testing has found:

- The formula works. `=XLOOKUP(F7-Time(0,2,0),Sheet2!A3:A100,Sheet2!B3:B100,"N/A")`
  As evidenced by it working with some dates, just not all.
- The calculated dates are actually in the other worksheet (I visually verified).  My calculated date in numeric form is 43983.3.  The date on Sheet2 in numeric form is 43983.3.  The manually typed date in numeric form is 43983.3.  The formula works with the manually typed one, but not the calculated one. Thus it is only a problem with calculated dates.
- It does not make a difference if the date calculation is in a separate cell by itself or calculated inside the xlookup formula.
- It is not a problem with the method of calculation of the date. I have three different calculation methods:`C3-0.0833` and `C3-(2*60)/1440` and `C3-Time(0,2,0)`.  All have the same result with the dates that don't work.
- I don't' think it is a rounding issue.  I have wrapped the date calculations in `Round(calculation,2)`. Same result.  And as I mentioned above, the numeric number of the date are exactly the same.

Here is an example of Sheet1: `6/1/2020 9:12`.  This is the cell reference of Date.  I then go to Sheet2, which looks like this Column A and B:`43983.30    1.1118`.  The Column A has a list of dates and values sorted by every minute, with a value in Column B.  I will take the `6/1/2020 9:12` date, and then subtract 2 hours to arrive at `6/1/2020 7:12`.  In numeric form this is 43983.3 calculated from the date in Sheet1.  Then, I lookup this date in Sheet2!A:A to find the same date, then return column B.

So I am stymied and am hoping someone can help me on this. I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: Small point maybe but Time(0,2,0) is 2 minutes, not 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you, your small point is well received.  I double checked, and you are correct.  But I just tested it, and it did not change the end result.

Comment: Examples of your data, desired and actual output, would be helpful in figuring out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are having rounding errors. You tried

```
Round(calculation,2)
```

but doesn't seem to go far enough. Your times are at 1 minute intervals which in Excel is 0.00069444...

You could try something like

```
Round(calculation,5)    ' Round to ~1 second resolution
```

That still may fail for some odd cases. A safer route could be to compare strings using the `TEXT` function, e.g.

```
TEXT(timevalue,"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm")
```

Comment: I tried rounding to 5, didn't fix it.  I also tried TEXT(timevalue,"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm"), but that didn't fix it either.  I think because Sheet2!A is a number, not text.

Comment: Convert both F7 and Sheet2!A to strings then compare.

Comment: Okay, found the solution.  As Xidgel said, you have to round.   But the part that I did not understand to do is you have to round the lookup value AND the lookup array, both.  I was only rounding one side.  Thank you Xidgel!